# setTimeout() not working with waitForKeyElements on Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, youtube, userscripts

I have a script that currently does away with those pesky "Continue watching?" prompts when autoplaying videos on YouTube using Tampermonkey and waitForKeyElements (in Google Chrome). They pop up every now and then if you just keep watching videos uninterrupted. Here's what I'm referring to:

[image: YouTube "Still watching?" popup]

And here's the script that eliminates them:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YouTube Yes SJ3
// @include  https://www.youtube.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-button-renderer:contains('Yes')", clicks);

function clicks (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    console.log('SJ3');
    waitForKeyElements ("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-button-renderer:contains('Yes')", clicks);
}
```

Although this script seems to successfully click away every "Continue Watching?" prompt,   according to the console, the script runs rapidly and indefinitely again and again if clicked on a second prompt (or on any video but the first in the autoplay sequence). Then, my CPU/RAM usage goes through the roof.

Now I'm not exactly sure the cause, but it's possible that the "Continue Watching?" prompts on any video besides the first is simply hidden after a click, which could be why the script tries to fire infinitely.

So to get around this, I figured I'd try to delay that last line of code in the function to simply check every 30 seconds after a click. So I used `setTimeout()`. Here's the updated code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YouTube Yes 10SJX
// @include  https://www.youtube.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-button-renderer:contains('Yes')", clicks);

function clicks (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    console.log('10Clicked');
    setTimeout(() => { waitForKeyElements ("a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-button-renderer:contains('Yes')", clicks); }, 30000);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to execute the `setTimeout()` line. It clicks the first prompt, but never the following ones when they appear. How do I successfully get my script to wait for X time before checking the selector again via waitForKeyElements?

Ultimately, how do I do away with recurring "Continue Watching?" prompts on YouTube using `waitForKeyElements`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`pause` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause_event) fired on `<video>` elements when they are paused. If you listen to that, check if the popup exists, then dismiss it, you should be fine:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     YouTube Yes 10SJX
// @include  https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
    const yesButtonSelector = "a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-button-renderer";

    videoElement.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        // the video has been paused; check if popup exists
        const yesButton = [...document.querySelectorAll(yesButtonSelector)]
            .find(element => element.innerText === 'Yes');
        if (!yesButton) return; // probably paused by user

        yesButton.click(); // dismiss
        videoElement.play(); // and resume
    });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, you've been incredibly helpful. I'm assuming I should remove the `contains:` part of the selector because it's jQuery? Or I guess I can add back the `@require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js`? I'm going to test it shortly.

Comment: So it seems to completely ignore the "Continue Watching?" prompt and continues to play (which is good in my case), but it will repeat the video that the prompt appears on, indefinitely. So I guess the new challenge is getting it to go to a new video when autoplaying through the video that gives the prompt. I'm thinking about maybe just forcing a refresh whenever the video pauses or that selector appears.